# 'str' object has no attribute 'ndim' keras

Tags: numpy, keras

I have a Keras model that I feed with numpy arrays as X_train, and y_train is something like `['0', '1', ...]`, with strings.
When I feed the model I obtain the error above, but I have this problem only using a custom image generator, while if I use the ImageDataGenerator keras class everything's fine. Do you have any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

This is ok:

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        shear_range=0.15,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        fill_mode="nearest")
def genOK(aug):
    (x, y) = next(aug.flow(np.array(x),y,batch_size=batch_size))
    yield x, y

model.fit_generator(genOK,...)
```

This is not:

```
my_data_augmentation_generator(X,y):
    while True:
        do some image transformations here
        yield X_transformed, y

my_aug = my_data_augmentation_generator()

def genNOTOK(my_aug):
    (x, y) = next(my_aug)
    yield x, y

model.fit_generator(genNOTOK,...)
```

Comment: Can you include the full error message, including line numbers etc?

Comment: Found. I'm stupid. The problem was that y was not a numpy array but a list of strings. with yield x, np.array(y) everything's fine

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured it out!